# How to iterate over first element of each nested tensor in tensorflow, python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with a tensor which looks as follows:

```
X = tf.constant([['a', 'y', 'b'],
              ['b', 'y', 'a'],
              ['a', 'y', 'c'],
              ['c', 'y', 'a'],
              ['a', 'y', 'd'],
              ['c', 'y', 'd'],
              ['b', 'y', 'c'],
              ['f', 'y', 'e']])
```

I wish to iterate over this in a manner that I am able to retrieve the first element of each nested tensor, i.e., 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c',... and perform some operation in that iteration.

I have tried using tf.slice() operation but I am new to tensorflow and am unable to figure out how to go about it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Probably you can get the vector of the first values simply like `X[:,0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have not evaluated the tensor yet. Use `tensor.eval()` or `session.run(tensor)` to evaluate the result:

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.constant([['a', 'y', 'b'],
              ['b', 'y', 'a'],
              ['a', 'y', 'c'],
              ['c', 'y', 'a'],
              ['a', 'y', 'd'],
              ['c', 'y', 'd'],
              ['b', 'y', 'c'],
              ['f', 'y', 'e']])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  for i in X[:,0].eval():
    element= i.decode("utf-8") 
    print(element)

  # Or using sess.run()
  #for j in sess.run(X[:,0]):
  #  element= j.decode("utf-8") 
  #  print(element)
```

Output:

```
a
b
a
c
a
c
b
f
```